# How does the Singleton class control when driver.quit() and driver.close() are called?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, singleton

If I comment out the driver.quit() and driver.close() lines, the calling test classes use the same driver and browser session, but obviously do not kill the driver and browser on completion of all test classes!

If I uncomment those 2 lines, the driver and browser session will be killed between test classes which defeats the purpose of the Singleton class.

Where and how does the Singleton/BaseTest class control when driver.quit() and driver.close() are called?

```
class Singleton {
    private static Singleton single_instance = null;   

    public static Singleton getInstance() { 
        if (single_instance == null) 
            single_instance = new Singleton();   
        return single_instance; 
    } 
} 
//-------------------------------------------
public abstract class BaseTest {
    protected static WebDriver driver;  
    static Singleton singleton = null;  

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        if(singleton == null) {
            singleton = Singleton.getInstance();        
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER"));
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        //driver.close();
        //driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right, that singleton has no purpose.  It doesn't control the driver (or anything else).

Comment: sry, didn't mean to troll, it's possible I'm not understanding something there, but I don't see the purpose of using a singleton at all here and the one you posted has an empty constructor.

Comment: Ok, I have 2 test classes that extend the BaseTest class. 'driver' is defined in the BaseTest.setUpBeforeClass() if singleton is null. I want the 2 test classes to use the same driver and browser session and kill the driver and browser only after all tests have completed. How do I achieve this?

Ok, I have removed the empty Singleton constructor as it did nothing.

Comment: gotcha... move driver initialization and tear-down outside of the base class.  Pass the driver in to the base class.  Doesn't seem like you need the base class at that point, though.  The point of that base class seems to be to run a single procedure/test.

Comment: How about a class that takes a list of tests to run?  It would initialize the driver, pass the driver into the test classes, run them in sequence, and then tear down the driver.

Comment: Best practice is to use one browser instance per test. The Singleton class is more complicated than is necessary but you basically have it set up correctly. You should instantiate the driver on `@BeforeTest` and then quit the driver on `@AfterTest`.

Comment: Why is it best practice to use one browser instance per test?
This makes the tests unnecessarily close and reopen the browser and takes longer.

Comment: I think it really depends on what the test is.  If it's a regression test tied to a specific bug-fix, you'd want to run only the procedures in that repeatable case.  If you are exploring/looking to find bugs it's advantageous to run different combinations/orders of procedures in the same driver session.

Comment: Also consider how reporting is handled.  Best to break down "tests" into procedures and actions.  Each driver action can pass/fail...if all actions in a procedures pass, the procedure passes, if all procedures pass, the "test" passes.